# Можно ли с помощью Retrofit получать отдельные поля из тела JSON?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Получаю Json:

```
{
 {"name":"name",
  "desc":"description"
 }
}
```

Можно ли получать только лишь "desc", чтобы не загружать тело целиком?

Comment: получаешь все, а вот выводишь только то, что нужно

Comment: В смысле сэкономить траффик на двух скобках после `"description"`?:D В общем случае можно скачать начало и не докачивать остальное - но для вашего примера это не подходит, нужна поддержка более конкретных запросов самим сервером.

Comment: woesss, я изначально не учел в вопросе, что это лишь пример. В реальности я получаю Json с гораздо большим количеством полей. Из Вашего комментария понял, что все-таки нужны более конкретные поддерживаемые сервером запросы для моей цели.